# Why can't I copy a part of my array in Node?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to set up an array in which a part is repeated twice. It consists of three articles (in articleArray[0] through articleArray[2]) and for each there's a list of every word in the article (for instance articleArray[1][1] lists each word in that article). I want to clone that last part to articleArray[1][2], but for some reason it won't work? I'm using a for-loop

```
for (var x=0; x < articleCount; x++) {
    for (var y=0; y < articleArray[x][1].length; y++) {
            articleArray[x][2] = [];
            articleArray[x][2][y] = articleArray[x][1][y];
        }
    }
```

After running that, each value in articleArray[1][2] is empty except the last one, for some reason. Why is it not copying my values?

Comment: You're re-initializing `articleArray[x][2]` to a new **empty** array each time through the loop!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're repeatedly overwriting `articleArray[x][2]` with an empty array. You will need to move the line

```
articleArray[x][2] = [];
```

one level up, outside of the inner loop:

```
for (var x=0; x < articleCount; x++) {
    articleArray[x][2] = [];
    for (var y=0; y < articleArray[x][1].length; y++) {
        articleArray[x][2][y] = articleArray[x][1][y];
    }
}
```

Notice that this can be simplified using [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to clone the array:

```
for (var x=0; x < articleCount; x++) {
    articleArray[x][2] = articleArray[x][1].slice();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this version?

```
articleArray.forEach(arr => {
  arr[2] = arr[1].slice();
});
```